# How can I remove "m" prefix from greenDAO's generated getters and setters?

Tags: android, greendao

GreenDAO is searching for getters and setters with the "m" prefix included in the name in its generated classes.

For example, I've set the entity to not generate any getters and setters but it still looks for, let's say, `getMDate()` for my `private Date mDate`, instead of my manually created `getDate()` method. Same goes for setters.

This is just breaking my adherence to the [Android Code Style Guidelines](https://source.android.com/source/code-style#follow-field-naming-conventions).

Is there any way to configure greenDAO to use the code style standards that I've set out in Android Studio when it generates code?

---

**EDIT**: Just to make things clearer, I've added some code to get my point across. I wrote the above question half knocked out on antihistamines due to having chronic hayfever while I was trying to work and just wanted to get to sleep so I apologise if it wasn't enough to work with.

```
@Entity(generateConstructors = false, generateGettersSetters = false)
public class Day {

    @Id
    private long mId;

    @Unique
    @NotNull
    private Date mDate;

    @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "mDayId")
    private List<Goal> mGoals;

    public Day(long id) {
        this.mId = id;

        mGoals = new ArrayList<Goal>();
    }

    public Day(long id, Date date) {
        this.mId = id;
        this.mDate = date;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        mId = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return mDate;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        mDate = date;
    }

    public List<Goal> getGoals() {
        return mGoals;
    }

    public void setGoals(List<Goal> goals) {
        mGoals = goals;
    }
}
```

Above is my `Day` class. As you can see I've disabled generation of the getters and setters in the `@Entity` annotation, and put my own in there. I've set up Android Studio to take the "m" into consideration when I use alt+enter to create getters and setters for each of my fields.

```
public Date getMDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public void setMDate(Date mDate) {
    this.mDate = mDate;
}
```

Here is an example of the getters and setters that greenDAO generates for my code given the field `private Date mDate`. This is breaking the code style guidelines in that the local variables include the "m" prefix and also that the method names include it as well (maybe a bit of a nit-pick there, but you can set up Android Studio so it doesn't do that which makes me think it shouldn't be like that).

With my getters and setters there, greenDAO still thinks the getters and setters are missing, which results in them being added twice. Once as the ones I put in, and another as what you see above. This also results in the generation of the code below.

```
@Override
protected final void bindValues(DatabaseStatement stmt, Day entity) {
    stmt.clearBindings();
    stmt.bindLong(1, entity.getMId());
    stmt.bindLong(2, entity.getMDate().getTime());
}

@Override
protected final void bindValues(SQLiteStatement stmt, Day entity) {
    stmt.clearBindings();
    stmt.bindLong(1, entity.getMId());
    stmt.bindLong(2, entity.getMDate().getTime());
}
```

Here is some of the code from the class `DayDao` which is generated from greenDAO. It's still using the names for the getters (and also setters) that it would have used to generate its own getters and setters (`getMDate()` instead of `getDate()`) if I didn't disable their generation on the `Day` entity class. I can't change this code because it just switches back the next time I build the project, and there is my problem.

My question is: how can I get greenDAO to take the "m" prefix thing into consideration when it generates its code and get it to use the getters and setters that I have set out myself? Or even get it to generate getters and setters itself without the "m" being included in the name and local variables?

Comment: Using an `m` prefix for fields that are non-static and non-public is standard.

Comment: @Gala yeah and that's what I'm doing. I fail to see your point

Comment: And all of us fail to understand your question. What are you trying to archive?

Comment: @Gala I'll update my question with code shortly

Comment: @Gala sorry if I was being difficult before. Hopefully, the added code and explanation of it all helps get my point across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I decided to use for this ended up being rather disappointing.

It involved just making my properties all `public` instead of `private`. Still conforming to the code style, these properties would no longer use the `m` prefix ... or any prefix, for that matter. It's not a very satisfactory solution as now my data can be accessed and set directly, just for a simple naming convention to be conformed to.

I (personally) disagree with people saying that using naming conventions hurts readability. If you structure your code well enough and give enough of a description in Javadoc comments and the like, you'll know exactly what something is doing. Having said that, if using the conventions is going to create such code as in my question above, then I guess that this is a situation where it does, and a reason not to use the code style in my other projects and still stick to the access that I want for my data.